# In a swimming race, the odds that A will win are $\frac23$ to $3$ and the odds that B will win are $\frac14$. Find the odds that A or B win the race.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logic, word-problem

**Problem :** In a swimming race, the odds that A will win are $\frac23$ and the odds that B will win are $\frac14$. Find the odds that A or B win the race.

**My Approach :** I guess we can add up the odds of A and B to find the odds of winning of 'A and B'. That is, $\frac23+\frac14=\frac{11}{12}.$ Am I correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add your own thoughts so we will see your efforts in the problem, this will be better for us to help you too.

Comment: You can add odds after taking common denominator. in this case both A and B cannot win together. Out of $5$ times, A wins $2$ times and B wins once, so A or B will win $3$ out of $5$ times or odds is $3$:$2$

Comment: Be clear first about the difference between **odds** and **probability.**  which a large number of people unfortunately seem to think are identical.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. There is a subtle distinction between odds and probability; $2:3$ odds is the probability $\frac{2}{2+3}$ and $1:4$ odds is $\frac{1}{1+4}$. With that in mind, you can sum the probabilities. The general formula for the probability A wins or B wins is
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
where $P(A \cup B)$ denotes the probability A wins or B wins, and $P(A \cap B)$ is probability A wins and B wins, which is clearly impossible. Thus it reduces to
$$= P(A) + P(B)$$
$$= \frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{5}$$
$$= \frac{3}{5}$$